# Why does my project break and doesn't compile when moving a unit test project I made with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

So I followed a tutorial [Introduction to Google Test and CMake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp1ifh9TuFI), which was working fine. But when I move the project folder to another directory, the project breaks and gives me this error:

```
FAILED: test/ExampleTests.exe
.
.
.
[build] LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use 
/NODEFAULTLIB:library
[build] test\ExampleTests.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

There's more to that but I don't want to bombard you with the stuff in between.

I moved the folder from `Desktop\Example` to `Desktop\HelloWorld\Example`.I tried deleting the build folder that it created and hitting F7 again but it kept giving me the error.

Folder structure

```
build\
googletest\
test\
    |CMakeLists.txt
    | ExampleTests.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
Example.cpp
Example.hpp
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12) 
set(This Example) 
project(${This} C CXX) 
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) 
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON) 
enable_testing() 
add_subdirectory(googletest) 
set(Headers Example.hpp 
) 
set(Sources Example.cpp 
) 
add_library(${This} STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers}) 
add_subdirectory(test)
```

**test\CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
set(This ExampleTests)
set(Sources
    ExampleTests.cpp
)
add_executable(${This} ${Sources})
target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC
    gtest_main
    Example
)
add_test(
    NAME ${This}
    COMMAND ${This}
)
```

**ExampleTests.cpp**:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
TEST(ExampleTest, blah)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(true, true);
}
```

**Example.cpp**:

```
#include "Example.hpp"
void Example::test()
{
    int x = 5;
}
```

**Example.hpp**:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_HPP
#define EXAMPLE_HPP
class Example
{
    public:
        void test();
};
#endif
```

Comment: Can you please paste your Example.cpp and Example.hpp as well?

Comment: @theWiseBro Updated. Wrote it from memory, I'm not on my dev computer right now.

Comment: It should be #define EXAMPLE_HPP. A typo perhaps? It certainly can lead to this multiple definition error.

Comment: @theWiseBro sorry that was a typo from typing it from memory.

Comment: Sounds like your configuration is corrupted somehow. Are you sure you are building the project generated in the *new* build directory location? `Desktop\HelloWorld\Example\build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I asked the original uploader of the video that I linked to for a solution and this solves my problem.

> Moving it to another folder will usually break things unless you clean out the build folder (just delete it or don't move it with the rest of the files).  The build folder contains intermediate build products that have path names in them, as well as CMake's cache (CMakeCache.txt) which also contains path names.

When I move to another directory I just move all the files, except for the build folder like he stated, opened up VS Code and it compiled.